# How to define a method in an interface that can return a list of any type without throwing unchecked assignment warnings?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface Data<T> {
    List<T> getData();
}
```

Implementation of the interface:

```
public class HealthData implements Data {

    public List<HealthDataEntry> getData() {

            // Do something
    }
}
```

When I invoke the method I get an unchecked assignment warning:

```
Data data = new HealthData();
List<HealthDataEntry> healthData = data.getData()   //Unchecked assignment warning thrown here
```

It works but the warning is annoying, can you please advice me on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class HealthData implements Data<HealthDataEntry>
```

And

```
Data<HealthDataEntry> data = new HealthData();
```

Otherwise you are using a raw type.